# Difference between "trans-ethnic" and "cross-ancestry"

Tags: human-genome, 1000genomes

A quick terminology question today. I see the terms "cross-ancestry" and "trans-ethnic" used seemingly interchangeably in literature. Is there any real difference between those two or are the 100% the same?